# Select Search bar disappear in small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, responsive

I have built form that search for IDs through search bar,
[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mJWQ.jpg)

when I turn the view to phone screen the search bar disappear.

[small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if1mx.jpg)
[iphone screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E69bb.png)

my code:

```
  <label for="supervisor"> </label>
  <br>
  <select  id="supervisor" class="chosen" onchange="getSuper(this.value)" required >
    <option disabled selected value>-</option>
    <option  value="ID3357">ID3357</option>
    <option  value="ID2695">ID2695</option>


  </select>
```

autocomplete search jquery

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".chosen").chosen();
  </script>
```

I relay on this video to add search bar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-gAPYRLMeI

Comment: Do you use different CSS for the different views? Can you share the relevant part of your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Use css media querys for diffrent widths like

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

according to your devices width apply them and apply diffrent functionality's in between them

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the JS functions,
please follow this link to solve the issue or to add in (small screen) search bar in dropdown

https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.